# Windows 8 javascript app: How to list all settings stored by the app

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

I am currently trying to build my 1st Windows 8 app in javascript. It's basically an alarmclock app with multiple alarms.

I wanted to store these alarms in roamingSettings, and then retrieve them. However I don't see a way how to retrieve a list of all settings stored without knowing their key. Examples such as this work with the key name available:

```
var value = roamingSettings.values["exampleSetting"];
```

I am going for something else: I want a list of all setings, because I am saving an unknown number of items. How to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.
Boris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`for in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over all keys in the object:

```
for (var key in roamingSettings.values)
```